# SQL Query in DotNetNuke

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I am using a Form & List module in DotNetNuke and would like to set up a query that filters the result set and returns the records submitted only by the user(without displaying everyone else)

I am not all familiar with the DNN tables and I think it would be something like below but I am not sure what goes into the WHERE clause...

I think it'd be

```
SELECT * FROM ---tablename--- WHERE ...
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Solution: insert a filter statement into the List Settings of the module:

```
[Created by_UDT_Original] = ‘[User:UserName]’
```

Answer (score 0):

The FNL module uses it's own table structure, so querying against it will be fairly complex, and will vary based on the columns and types you created when configuring the module.

That being said, it is possible to have the module only display an individual user's data, that is either configured through the Module Settings, or within the FnL configuration itself.

Comment: I may have forgotten the Search option use in the module in my original post. Right now if a user enters a last name different from his/her own - he gets to see those records.; and of course, the goal is to have only his/her records returned through Search.   P.S. I have checked the box for "Manipulate only user's records" under settings and still able to see others records.

Comment: I've figured it out! In order for Form and List module to return only the records submitted by current user a filter expression is needed to be inserted into the List Settings of the module!                                                                 [Created by_UDT_Original] = ‘[User:UserName]’